# How to create resource-based policy for AWS pinpoint using CloudFormation (CFN)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

[This AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/security_iam_resource-based-policy-examples.html) has some examples for resource based policies for AWS pinpoint but I am not able to understand where to put this policy document for a new pinpoint application(project) via CFN. The CFN for [AWS::Pinpoint::App](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-pinpoint-app.html) does not seem to have a policy attribute.

Does anyone know where to plugin the resource-based policy for pinpoint app?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, pinpoint **doesn't support** resource-based policies.

The types of IAM policies available for pinpoint are listed in the following table:

- [Customer Engagement Services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html#engagement_svcs)

To be sure I also checked pinpoint [aws cli for poinpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/pinpoint/index.html) and couldn't  locate any information about resource-based policies for pinpoint.

I not sure what the documentation you linked is referring to. Probably for some other resources that can interact with pinpoint, e.g. a lambda function.